# If $AB=-I_n$, then prove that $det(I_n+BA)=2^n$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Given two matrices $A,B\in \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ and $AB=-I_n$, prove that:
$$det(I_n+BA)=2^n$$

We know that: $2^n=det(2\cdot I_n)=det(I_n+I_n)$ and $I_n+BA=-(-I_n-BA)=-(AB+BA)$.

How can I get $BA=I_n$ to substitute in the previous equation?

Comment: The result seems to be wrong, try $A=I_n$ and $B=-I_n$ then the determinant on the left is $0$. Either you need $AB=I_n$ or $I_n - BA$ inside the determinant.

Comment: Actually this exercise was on exam. I never figured that out! Thank you.

Comment: We have $$ I + BA = B(B^{-1} + A) = B(I + AB)B^{-1},$$ that is $I + BA = 0$ under the given hypotheses.

Comment: @DanielC : Maybe you want to say $\det (I-BA)=2^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $AB = I$, then $B$ is a right-inverse to $A$. Therefore it is also a left-inverse, so $BA = I$. Thus $\det(I + BA) = \det(2I) = 2^n$.

*Note.* I assume $AB = I$ because the hypothesis $AB = -I$ appears erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

One of the two signs is definitely wrong.

So Assume that $AB=I$. Then $BA=I$ and $\det(I+BA)=\det( 2I)=2^n\det I=2^n$.

If $AB=-I$, then $A(-B)=I$, and hence $(-B)A=I$ or $BA=-I$, and again $\det (I-BA)=\det(2)I=2^n$.